# How to update a table only if the update results in a change of values?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, temporal-tables

I use [system-versioned tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) in my SQL Server database, which has a number of tables with parent/child relationships. I am writing a stored procedure to update a set of parent/child tables using parameters supplied to the procedure.

With system-versioned tables, a new row will be created in the history table whenever an UPDATE command is run, even if none of the values have changed. To avoid creating numerous rows in my history table that are identical to rows in my temporal table, I would like this SP to *only* update a table when a value supplied by a parameter is different from a value that already exists in the table row.

Based on similar questions I've seen, I know I could include something in the WHERE statement to do this (i.e., WHERE @Param <> [Value]); however, I will be dealing with a large number of different tables and values, so I was hoping to find a more scalable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of using `@Param <> ColumnName` syntax for something like this; if either value is `NULL` then this expression will resolve the UNKNOWN, which *isn't* TRUE, and so the row *isn't* affected. The more complete version would be:

```sql
WHERE (@Param <> ColumnName
   OR  (@Param IS NULL AND ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
   OR  (@Param IS NOT NULL AND ColumnName IS NULL))
```

For *a lot* of `NULL`able columns that becomes *very* long.

In newer versions of SQL Server you can use `IS DISTINCT FROM` instead, which will treat an expression like `NULL IS DISTINCT FROM 1` as TRUE and `NULL IS DISTINCT FROM NULL` as FALSE.

This, much like the solution you have, involves a lot of `OR` clauses:

```sql
...
FROM ...
WHERE @Param1 IS DISTINCT FROM Col1
   OR @Param2 IS DISTINCT FROM Col2
   OR @Param3 IS DISTINCT FROM Col3
   ...
   OR @Param15 IS DISTINCT FROM Col15
```

An alternative method I quite like is to use an `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECT` in a `(NOT) EXISTS)`, and `SELECT` the parameters in one and the columns in the other. This would look something like this:

```sql
...
FROM ...
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ..., Col15
              EXCEPT
              SELECT @Param1, @Param2, @Param3, ..., @Param15);
```

If all the columns and parameters have the *same* value then a row won't be returned in the subquery, and so the `EXISTS` returns FALSE and the row isn't updated. Like `IS DISTINCT FROM`, this will handle `NULL` values, as `SELECT NULL EXCEPT SELECT NULL;` will result in no returned rows.

Comment: In the latter predicate it's not unthinkable that `Col1 = @param2` and `Col2 = @param1`.

Comment: `EXCEPT`/`INTERSECT` compare based on ordinal positions, `@Param1` won't be compared to `Col2` as they are in different ordinal positions, @Gert .

Comment: You're right, I confused it with a a select from `values`. Is it also plan-friendly?

Comment: @GertArnold - mostly. For the equality version it can do an index seek with `IS` semantics. https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html Though I have found that when using this in more complex cases that sometimes I get a better execution plan with the more long winded rewrite - so I would always check the execution plan when using this

Comment: Also `NOT EXISTS ... INTERESCT` can sometimes fare better that `EXISTS...EXCEPT` https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204014/3690 - which was a point made in the comments of the original article (way back machine https://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

Comment: OK, so all in all it's a nice alternative I hadn't seen before. Nice to have it in the toolbox.